# error encoding text. unable to encode text using charset windows-1256 jgrasp

Tags: java, windows, encoding, jgrasp

when ever i want to save the file, i receive this message: error encoding text. unable to encode text using charset windows-1256. First bad character is at line 3 column 1.

simply this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
static Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main (String [] args){

}}
```

## Solution :

the problem was that i had another opened class with invalid character written in a comment

Comment: It might be helpful to tell a bit more. Like what kind of IDE you're using (If you're using one).

Answer (score 0):

Did you paste this code in from somewhere else (web page, Word document)?

As pasted here, the code is valid for 1256, but the paste or the formatting probably corrected the problem.

Possibly there is some zero-width character at the start of line three that you aren't seeing. Use the right and left arrow keys to "step" through that area, and if you find it (need to hit left or right arrow twice to move cursor once), delete it.

Or, it's possible that the curly bracket at the end of line two is not a standard one. You can use the arrow keys to move the cursor around in the problem area and watch the "Code" value shown in the message bar for anything 128 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in binary mode. This worked for me in JGrasp